# How does MVC in iOS work?

Tags: ios, model-view-controller

Can someone please give me a few examples of a Controller object? From what I understand, model objects are the ones you create in code right? Like methods for updating your views, putting text on a label, etc. And in views I have labels, buttons ,etc. In between those two, I have Controller objects that link those two together. But what objects are these?

Comment: See Apple's [Cocoa Core Competencies: Model-View-Controller](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/MVC.html).

Comment: In answer to your question, no, model objects do not generally include methods for updating views, labels, etc. That's the job of the controller. Model objects are just types that represent data only (e.g. a `Employee` object has `firstName`, `lastName`, `department`, `employeeID`, etc., properties, perhaps a `fullName` method that renders a combined full name, etc.).

Comment: MVC takes a bit to learn, it works no differently in iOS, which would be Objective C and Swift or another programming language, it is a bit of an art form I guess. The design pattern allows flexibility and different programming styles, you should read up on MVC design patterns to better understand, it has nothing to do with iOS